# Why a scroll bar's maximum scroll position is (MaxRangeValue - (PageSize - 1)) rather than (MaxRangeValue - PageSize)?

Tags: winapi, user-interface, scrollbar

I’m learning Windows programming, there’s something about scroll bar’s scroll range and page size I don’t understand.

Based On http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787527.aspx,

```
MaxScrollPos = MaxRangeValue - (PageSize - 1)
```

But why? I think it’s better if

```
MaxScrollPos = MaxRangeValue - PageSize
```

If I want to display an bitmap whose height is 2000px, and the client height is 600px, It’s natural to set scroll range to [0, 2000], and page size to 600. When the scroll position is 0, the top of the bitmap is displayed; when the scroll position is 1400, the bottom of the bitmap is displayed. But If I do so, I’m able to set the scroll position to 2000 - (600 - 1) = 1401. What does position 1401 mean if 1400 should display the bottom? If “MaxScrollPos” did equal “MaxRangeValue - PageSize”, everything will work perfectly. Now I have to set the scroll range to [0, 1999] to avoid the problem. I think it’s unnatural. So, is there anyone who can explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range from 0 to 1999 covers 2000 values. It's a zero-based index, whereas your pixel size count starts from 1.

Comment: But MSDN says: “if an application must display 260 lines of a text file in a window that can show only 16 lines at a time, the vertical scroll bar range can be set to 1 through 244. If the scroll box is at position 1, the first line will be at the top of the window. If the scroll box is at position 244, the last line (line 260) will be at the bottom of the window.” Is the range should be 1 to 260?

Comment: Exactly! - starting at 1. not 0.

Comment: MSDN says 1 to 244, not 1 to 260. Also, should I use 1 to 260 or 0 to 259?